# How to create this page in jsp

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

ajax jquery how to create a jsp page like this please help me out in creating this.
I have a JSP page which loads another jsp page's content which is working perfectly fine.

The problem is I want to pass `request.getParameter("cfgname")` to this content page, so that when it is loaded into the main JSP the content is complete. (Current code shows me null in place of request.getParameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can put the parameters' session 'and' request ',  to achieve the goal of passing parameters.
<%
    session.setAttribute(name,value);

    request.setAttribute(name,value);
%>
<%
    value=(value className)session.getAttribute(name);

    value=(value className)request.getAttribute(name);
%>
```